# How to create a comprehensive bibliography with splitbib?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, splitbib

I need to split my bibliography into separate sections. The [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package pefectly matches my needs but, unfortunately, does not support my customized [apacite](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/apacite) style.
Thus, I have to resort to the [`splitbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/splitbib) package. What is really annoying, however, is that `splitbib` requires definition of every single source to be included in the bibliography.
Since I am writing a book with several hundreds of references, manually defining the `\SBentries{}` command is not an option for me. `biblatex` has this really cool feature to separate bib entires by reference to keywords in the `.bib` file. Is there a similar option for `splitbib` to replace the individual entries in `\SBentries{}` by composite entries defined by keywords?

A mwe (without solution) looks like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{splitbib}
\begin{category}[A]{First Category}
\SBentries{B1,B2}
\end{category}
\begin{category}[B]{Second Category}
\SBentries{A1}
\end{category}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\bibname.bib}
 @BOOK{B1,
  author =       {Name1, Surname1},
  title =        {Title of the first book in the First category},
  publisher =    {Name of the Publisher},
  year =         {2017},
  keywords =     {firstcategory}
}
@BOOK{B2,
  author =       {Name2, Surname2},
  title =        {Title of the second book in the First category},
  publisher =    {Name of the Publisher},
  year =         {2016},
  keywords =     {firstcategory}
}
@ARTICLE{A1,
  author =       {Name3, Surname3},
  title =        {This is the title of first article in the Second category},
  journal =      {Name of the Journal},
  year =         {2017},
  volume =       {01},
  number =       {12},
  pages =        {1-20},
  keywords =     {secondcategory}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
I split my bibliography in two section by using the splitbib package. Authors \cite{B1,B2} with the keyword "firstcategory" in the bib. file should appear in the First Category and authors \cite{A1} with the keyword "secondcategory" should appear in the Second Category.
\bibliography{\bibname}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of trying to adapt splitbib why don't you adapt the biblatex style?

Comment: I really appreciate `biblatex` over `bibtex`. But have you ever tried to migrate a highly customized bib style from `bibtex` to `biblatex`? This is definitely way beyond my tex skills.

Comment: You need tex-skills for both solutions so this is not an argument to reject one way. There is a biblatex-apa-style which should be quite near to whatever you want. And by asking good questions (with complete minimal examples!) it should be easy to get the rest. If you want to get the splitbib way you should provide a minimal example that demonstrates your problem too. I at least won't spent my time to build a test environment based on your rather vage description.

Comment: Well, as I said, I am somehow committed to `bibtex`.  My question aims at adjusting the `splitbib` command for `\SBentries{entry1,entry2,entry3,entry4,entry5,entry_n}`. Is there a way to simplify this command to include all entries that share a common keyword? I do not know how a mwe could help here to be more clear on this.

Comment: Why don't you simply believe me when I say that you should provide a minimal example?

Comment: Because (1) I do not get your argument, and (2) my mwe does not include any problem. But maybe I have valued parsimony over precision. Sorry, if that is the case. I have now inluded a mwe as you have requested.

Comment: The main feature of an MWE is that you can run *tests* with it -- sometimes to test a problem and sometimes to test a solution. Beside this: if your special bst stores the keywords in a usable form in the bbl (apacite in your example doesn't) there is a small possibility to retrieve the keys and their category through the .aux-file. But imho it would be much less trouble to use biblatex.